# Should I nest functions in languages that allow me to do that or should I rather avoid it?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

In JavaScript, PL/SQL and some other languages, functions can be nested, i.e. declared within another function. This could be used to break a large function into smaller pieces, but keep those pieces within the context of the larger function.

```
function doTooMuch() {
    function doSomething () {
       ...
    }
    function doSomethingElse() {
       ...
    }
    function doYetAnotherThing() {
       ...
    }

    // doTooMuch body

    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
    doYetAnotherThing();
}
```

In some cases, when those smaller functions do not use local variables of the larger function, this could easily changed to a version where all functions are unnested.

```
function doSomething () {
   ...
}
function doSomethingElse() {
   ...
}
function doYetAnotherThing() {
   ...
}
function doTooMuch() {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
    doYetAnotherThing();
}
```

Assuming that those nested functions are not to be used anywhere else, is it better to keep them within the context of the large function or is it bad because this is exactly what makes the large function, well, large?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a matter of opinion, but I would avoid nesting functions unless it was actually a necessary and deliberate part of your design.

When you nest functions, in most languages, you end up with some sort of mechanical effect.  The most common, and interesting, is to close over the lexical scope of a variable that can be used inside the body, but others (eg: visibility of the function) also show up some of the time.

Those are typically awesome tools, when used right - but they are complex tools, because they can result in non-local or non-obvious effects when you first glance at the code.

If you don't use them, many people will read the code and not see anything doing that - so will assume they missed it, and look again, trying to work out why you did it that way, and not in a separate scope.

You also risk that future programmers will deliberately or even accidentally close over something they didn't intend to, by not noticing the risk right there.

Finally, if your function declaration declares a named function outside the scope of the enclosing function, just avoid it.  That is super confusing to everyone.

As to the final note: because individual functions help delimit code, nesting functions is less troublesome than a single giant function, but ultimately it *does* mean reading a lot more code to understand `doTooMuch()` - especially if you can hide code between the nested function declarations, or need to check that nobody did.

Comment: -1: Javascript is not "most languages". Nesting functions in Javascript is normal practice.

Comment: @kevincline nesting functions in JavaScript is a common bad practice

Comment: @Raynos: If you don't nest them, where are you going to put them?  Thee are no classes to contain them.  Here is some typical code: `jquery(function($){ $('#id').click(function(){...}); }`

Comment: @kevincline ... Typical code for noobs, you need functions nested one deep. And that's because javascript has no module scope, so you need that anonymous closure.

Comment: And if that click executes an Ajax call, with a completion callback?  Now you have functions nested two levels.  Sure, you could limit the nesting by assigning the anonymous closures to variables.  Is that really better?

Comment: I stand by my "matter of opinion" - but I will not, @kevincline, that your example is a "necessary and deliberate part of the design".  In PL/SQL it would be a much worse idea - and nesting for the sake of nesting in JavaScript is, I think, a bad idea for the reasons I named.  So, I don't disagree that it is common in JavaScript, just that it should be a first port of call - use it only if separate top level functions don't make sense or make the code distinctly worse - and don't declare nested **NAMED** functions.

Comment: +1: and I agre with you (and disagree with kevin). Closures surely are common as a JavaScript idioms, but it doesn't mean that declaring internal functions is a best practice. In fact, they are way too often misunderstood in terms of side-effects. And Kevin, of course you can put them somewhere. JavaScript has a global scope, and you are free to namespace your project according any method you want, which is precisely what your jquery snippet does.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those questions that have no right answer and words like "personal preference", "team practice" come to mind. In my opinion, little functions (now here's another subjective thing) that aren't used anywhere belong inside their parent functions, especially when they can be unnamed.

Answer (score 1):

This question has no right answer, because neither choice maximizes encapsulation. If you nest them, they still have access to variables they shouldn't. If you don't, then other functions have access to functions they shouldn't. Either way, you lose.